# DensityClust Package

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, density-plot

I am testing out this new package called `densityClust` in R. The documentation for it is provided here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/densityClust/densityClust.pdf

From this example below, what is the most optimal way of deciding what rho and delta are when determining your clusters? It looks like they just chose 2 for rho and 2 for delta in this case but there was no reasoning behind it and that seems to be the most important part. Also, when calculating `irisDist`, you can extract the rho's and delta's from when doing `irisClust$rho` and `irisClust$delta` but that doesn't help you in determining the clusters in this dataset.

```
library(densityClust)
iris<-iris
irisDist <- dist(iris[,1:4])
irisClust <- densityClust(irisDist, gaussian=TRUE)
plot(irisClust) # Inspect clustering attributes to define thresholds
irisClust <- findClusters(irisClust, rho=2, delta=2)
plotMDS(irisClust)
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Delta-Rho Plot:

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "most optimal" (optimality is a binary property)... :-P I am also all but convinced by this algorithm because you have to magically guess these two parameters, and the authors did not compare well to the state of the art.

Comment: Ok thanks for feedback, yeah I was just wondering how that came up or if there is a way from this package that you can choose these two parameters wisely. @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Read the paper. The authors suggest a heuristic approach that should work for tiny data like iris.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I read the paper, and even when I test it out there is no way to retrieve the values they said such as rho=2, delta=2

Comment: Csn you reproduce their delta-rho-plot?

Comment: Just added it @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Based on thar plot, I would have chosen 2 and 1, actually. But it's subjective.

Comment: Thanks, so that's what I am saying, is there a better way to extract the rho and delta rather than by just looking at the plot? @Anony-Mousse

Comment: I don't think they proposed a numerical approach. One of the many weaknesses of that paper.

Comment: ok no worries, thank you for looking into this @Anony-Mousse